# Knockout.JS: My console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" when i try to search something

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I want to create a search and dropdown filter with knockout JS. My dropdown filter works perfectly but when I try to search for a location, my console gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

```js
ko.utils.stringStartsWith = function(string, startsWith) {
  string = string || " ";
  if (startsWith.length > string.length) return false;
  return string.substring(0, startsWith.length) == startsWith;
};

var Record = function(dropType, dropName, dropAddress, homeTown) {

  this.dropType = dropType;
  this.dropName = dropName;
  this.dropAddress = dropAddress;
  this.homeTown = homeTown;

};

var ViewModel = function(records, homeTowns) {
  var self = this;
  self.homeTowns = ko.observableArray(homeTowns);
  self.records = ko.observableArray(
    ko.utils.arrayMap(records, function(r) {
      return new Record(r.dropType, r.dropName, r.dropAddress, r.homeTown);
    }));



  // search filter
  self.dropTypeSearch = ko.observable('');
  self.dropNameSearch = ko.observable('');
  self.townSearch = ko.observable('');

  self.filteredRecords = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.records(), function(x) {
      return (self.dropNameSearch().length == 0 || ko.utils.stringStartsWith(x.dropName.toLowerCase(), self.dropNameSearch().toLowerCase())) && (self.townSearch().length == 0 || x.homeTown == self.townSearch())
    });
  });
};



var homeTowns = ["Search Location", "Kalk Bay", "Simon's Town", "Muizenberg", "Claremont"];



var data = [{}, {
  id: 1,
  dropType: "Shelter",
  dropName: "The Haven, Kalk Bay",
  dropAddress: "139 Main Road, Kalk Bay",
  homeTown: "Kalk Bay",
}, {
  id: 2,
  dropType: "Shelter",
  dropName: "Happy Valley Simon's Town",
  dropAddress: "Palace Hill Road, Simon's Town",
  homeTown: "Simon's Town",
}, {
  id: 3,
  dropType: "Meals",
  dropName: "Living Grace Community Centre",
  dropAddress: "171 Main Road, Muizenberg",
  homeTown: "Muizenberg",
}, {
  id: 4,
  dropType: "Shelter",
  dropName: "The Haven, Claremont",
  dropAddress: "PO Box 23999, Claremont, 5 Fir Street",
  homeTown: "Claremont",
}, ];



ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data, homeTowns));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

//search input Name: <input data-bind="value: dropNameSearch, valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup'" /> Location: <select data-bind="options: homeTowns, value: townSearch"></select> //drop-down filter
<div data-bind="foreach: filteredRecords" class="record">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Type: <span data-bind="text: dropType"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      Name: <span data-bind="text: dropName"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      Address: <span data-bind="text: dropAddress"> </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      Location: <span data-bind="text: homeTown"></span>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

I am new to Knockout.js. JS fiddle or snippet run would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an empty object in your data so this will cause the properties of Record instance to be undefined. One way to get rid your error is to add default values to your Record function.

```
var Record = function(dropType, dropName, dropAddress, homeTown) {
    this.dropType = dropType || "";
    this.dropName = dropName || "";
    this.dropAddress = dropAddress || "";
    this.homeTown = homeTown || "";
};
```

This will ensure that all the properties will be string type and will fix the error.

However, there are  still some errors in the logic of your code in `filteredRecords` computed variable. If there is a value in `dropNameSearch()` and the `townSearch()` value is `"Search Location"`, then the results will still be empty since there is no data that has a `homeTown` value of `"Search Location"`.

To fix this, follow the order of this logic:

1. If `dropNameSearch` is empty and `townSearch` is "Search Location", then return `[]`.
2. If there is value in `dropNameSearch`, then do an initial filtering based on its value.
3. If the value of `townSearch` is not `"Search Location"`, then do a secondary filtering based on its value.

Here is a sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8z5Lmcau/

Comment: You're welcome. I would appreciate it if you would "Accept" the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because the function is part of the window object, not the input element object. So, computed function, you are calling a function that is part of the window object. The this object will refer to the window. Using call or apply, you can change the reference of this to another object. In this case, your input field. When you get a chance, research "call" and "apply". It will help you understand it a lot better.